# Set alternate languages with JSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, jsom

I am creating SharePoint 2013 sites using JavaScript (JSOM). I want to set alternate languages (languages already installed in farm) with JSOM, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the Language ID parameter to the below method sets the language of the new site
**SP.WebCreationInformation.set_language( <Language Id> );**

```
createWebsite(1045);
function createWebsite(languageId) {

var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

var webCreationInfo = new SP.WebCreationInformation();
webCreationInfo.set_title('My 1045 website');
webCreationInfo.set_description('Description of new Web site...');
webCreationInfo.set_language(languageId);
webCreationInfo.set_url('My1045WebSite');
webCreationInfo.set_useSamePermissionsAsParentSite(true);
webCreationInfo.set_webTemplate("STS#0");

oWebsite.get_webs().add(webCreationInfo);
oWebsite.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            console.log("Done");
            }, function(sender,args) { 
            console.log("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
        });
}
```

I have listed the language ID below,

**Locale ID -   Language**
1025 - Arabic 
1068 - Azerbaijani 
1069 - Basque 
5146 - Bosnian (Latin) 
1026 - Bulgarian 
1027 - Catalan 
2052 - Chinese (Simplified) 
1028 - Chinese (Traditional) 
1050 - Croatian 
1029 - Czech 
1030 - Danish 
1164 - Dari 
1043 - Dutch 
1033 - English 
1061 - Estonian 
1035 - Finnish 
1036 - French 
1110 - Galician 
1031 - German 
1032 - Greek 
1037 - Hebrew 
1081 - Hindi 
1038 - Hungarian 
1057 - Indonesian 
2108 - Irish 
1040 - Italian 
1041 - Japanese 
1087 - Kazakh 
1042 - Korean 
1062 - Latvian 
1063 - Lithuanian 
1071 - Macedonian 
1086 - Malay 
1044 - Norwegian (Bokmål) 
1045 - Polish 
1046 - Portuguese (Brazil) 
2070 - Portuguese (Portugal) 
1048 - Romanian 
1049 - Russian 
10266 - Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia) 
9242 - Serbian (Latin, Serbia) 
1051 - Slovak 
1060 - Slovenian 
3082 - Spanish 
1053 - Swedish 
1054 - Thai 
1055 - Turkish 
1058 - Ukrainian 
1066 - Vietnamese 
1106 - Welsh

Comment: This is for setting default language of the site, but I'm trying to add alternate languages.